# Re-using JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two methods that pretty much does the same thing.
I would like to improve this by just re-using the other method, something like method overriding in an Object Oriented Programming.

**Method 1 Summary:** Based on the `level`, make a `post` request to a Servlet that returns all the courses for that particular level in JSON format (`response`). Then load these courses to the combo box (`$loadTo`). After that pre-select a `course` provided and show some modal.

```
function loadCoursesByLevelThenSet(level, course, $loadTo) {
    $.post( ... , ... ,
    function(response) {

        var options = '<option value="">Please select course...</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            ...
        }

        $loadTo.html(options);

        $loadTo.val(course);
        $('#modal').modal('show');

    }).fail(function() {

        alert('Something went wrong while loading options for courses. Please try again.');

    });
}
```

**Method 2 Summary:** Based on the `level`, make a `post` request to a Servlet that returns all the courses for that particular `level` in JSON format (`response`), then load these courses to the combo box (`$loadTo`).

```
function loadCoursesByLevel(level, $loadTo) {
    $.post( ... , ... ,
    function(response) {

        var options = '<option value="">Please select course...</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            ...
        }

        $loadTo.html(options);

    }).fail(function() {

        alert('Something went wrong while loading options for courses. Please try again.');

    });
}
```

This is what I came up, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
function loadCoursesByLevelThenSet(level, course, $loadTo) {
    if (loadCoursesByLevel(level, $loadTo) === true) { 

        //after the courses are fully loaded  
        //select a course
        //and show the modal

        $loadTo.val(course);
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
}

function loadCoursesByLevel(level, $loadTo) {
    $.post( ... , ... ,
    function(response) {

        var options = '<option value="">Please select course...</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            ...
        }

        $loadTo.html(options);

    }).fail(function() {

        alert('Something went wrong while loading options for courses. Please try again.');

    }).done(function() {        

        return true;

    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempted solution is you can't return a value because the ajax is asynchronous.

You could pass a callback to `loadCoursesByLevel()`, and have it run after it runs its own success code. By checking if the callback is undefined, you can make it optional for more flexibility.

```
function loadCoursesByLevel(level, $loadTo, callback) {
    $.post( ... , ... ,
    function(response) {
        var options = '<option value="">Please select course...</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="'
                    + response[i].code + '">'
                    + response[i].course + '</option>';
        }
        $loadTo.html(options);

        if(typeof callback != 'undefined'){
            callback(); // <------------- execute callback
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong while loading options for courses. Please try again.');
    });
}

function loadCoursesByLevelThenSet(level, course, $loadTo) {
    loadCoursesByLevel(level, $loadTo, function() { 
        $loadTo.val(course);
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
}
```

Comment: You could pass the callback to the done function on the promise -- the `return true` there does nothing.